# Export Tracking Data from Marketing

Tags: marketing-cloud, tracking-extract

I need to export tracking data (sent, opens, bounces, etc.)  in  CSV file from Marketing Cloud to a Data warehouse through sFTP folder.
I would use the system data extension as explained [here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_sent/) and retrieve email's names and Job's names.
Do you have any suggestions how can i do this?

Comment: Please go through your questions, and mark answers as accepted - I see you have so far only done this on few of your questions, and mostly where the answer was provided by yourself. As a community, everyone here appreciates to know if they have been helpful to you or not.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably find the Tracking Extract more useful for your purposes, than Data Views, if what you'd like to do is push this data to SFTP for your DWH. These are somewhat more comprehensive than Data Views and would give you the name of the email from the Job extract.

See [Tracking Extract Output](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/tracking_extract_output/) for details of what's available. If you do not have Tracking Extracts available as an Extract Type in Email -> Interactions -> Data Extracts or in Automation Studio Activities when you're defining a Data Extract, create a case with Support to have them provisioned to your account.

Answer (score 0):

If tracking data of the last 30 days is sufficient for your needs, you could just use an automation with a data extract activity.

**Further information:**

- [Data Extract Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/)
- [Extract Types Reference](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/extract_types_reference/)